# file_save_data() cannot save to private://

Tags: files

I have to write a custom module extension, that saves entityform submission after hitting submit button to a PDF file in the `private://pdf/<file_name>` uri.

At first step it generates the PDF file to a temp directory via TCPDF and then I try to use `file_save_data` to save it to private directory and upload the file data to the db.

When I upload the file to the public directory, there are no problems, but when I set the uri to `private://<pathname/filename>` it sends me an error message:

> "The data could not be saved, because the destination is invalid. More information is available in the system log".

In the system log:

> "The data could not be saved because the destination private://pdf/employee_aontest_richie_2014-06-03_00_00_00_59.pdf is invalid. This may be caused by improper use of file_save_data() or a missing stream wrapper."

The code, that should save the whole thing is this:

```
$title = $node->title; // TCPDF doesn't let you have spaces or colons in your file name
$title_exploded = explode(' ', $title);
$title_imploded = implode('_', $title_exploded);
$imp_exploded = explode(':', $title_imploded);
$imp_exp_imploded = implode('_', $imp_exploded);
$real_title = drupal_strtolower($imp_exp_imploded);
//end of title generation
$save_path = 'private://pdf/'.$real_title.'.pdf';
$handle = fopen($full_path_tcpdf_output, 'r');
$file = file_save_data($handle, $save_path);
fclose($handle);
unlink($full_path_tcpdf_output);
```

I think the file saving procedure should work this way as it works if I save to public.

I appreciate any further advices.

Comment: Have you configured the private filesystem? Is in /admin/config/media/file-system. Also, check that the private://pdf directory is created.

Comment: Thanks! It worked well. Didn't know I had to configure the private directory, because I tought that it has a default directory.

Comment: Let's move this to an answer to reflect is answer (and is right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check two things:

- The private flesystem is configured: look in
  /admin/config/media/file-system.
- The destination directory (private://pdf) is created. The exact path
  of private:// depends on where have tou configured the private
  filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **file_save_upload()**  function of drupal to save pdf file ,i used this function in my site and saved in private:// , and pdf file is uploaded easily their,
Code that i have used in my site:-

// In form put this code

```
    $form['uploadrecord'] = array(
        '#type'=>'file',               
        '#title'=>'Upload Pdf',   
        '#attributes'=>array('class'=>array('upload_file')), 
     );
```

// at form submit put this code

```
$validators=array();

      $file_upload_record = file_save_upload('uploadrecord',$validators, 'private://pdf/'.$real_title.'.pdf');
```

and checkout the permissions of pdf directory too.may this code will work for you.